# Why android paid app installs are more than successful orders?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

As you can see photo below, the app (which is Paid) was installed in 5 devices.

[image]

But I only saw 3 orders in the orders report section, also only one of them was successful and it's actually a test order processed by me.

[image]

How this could be possible?

Comment: Please let me know what I did wrong after clicking the downvote button, I get banned from asking questions for more than 1 year, so I want to know what is my mistakes to improve myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the latest Google Pay Api users are able to refund their money within 48h. You should check user purchase situation every time user uses it, at least up until then.